How to add .env variables in vite.config.ts to use proxy server in React Typescript project?
I am building a react typescript project using vite run time. I need to define different base urls for different stages. For that following is my current implementation. But, I am getting some typescript error.
.env.development
VITE_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8080/

.env.production
VITE_API_BASE_URL=http://www.something.com/

vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],

  build: {
    outDir: 'build',
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 3000,
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL,
      },
    },
  },
})

Problem: I am getting type error for
target: import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL,

To fix this issue, I followed the vite doc. And added following code at vite-env.d.ts
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

interface ImportMetaEnv {
    readonly VITE_API_BASE_URL: string
    // more env variables...
}

interface ImportMeta {
    readonly env: ImportMetaEnv
}

But, nothing works. Is there any solution for that?

